# How to locate/edit the original source html of an aspx page on a sharepoint site

Tags: html, sharepoint-2007

I am working with a MOSS 2007 site, the page I am currently trying to make additions/changes to specifically is a popup.

The page is an .aspx file and I know where it is located, but simply put I am trying to find and ultimately modify the original source html of this page(the html which shows up when you hit "view source" when brought up in my browser).

When i try to edit the page in sharepoint designer It only brings up a formatted view of the html code, I wish to see a much more complete version where i can edit the attributes of the tags and such.

Is there anyway to locate this original source html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to do quick find and then search your HTML tag id or any descriptive text you can find from viewing source or expecting the element. And then select **Search Entire Solution** or **Current Project.**

Comment: You will need to be in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If the project is set up with a MVC structure, try finding

**MainFolder/ProjectName_Web/Views**

Alternately look in

**MainFolder/ProjectName_Web/UserControls**

If you are using Visual Studio, check out Kris Hollenbeck's solution.